# How can I change the color of a mouse hover underline using CSS?

Tags: html, css, underline

How can I change the color of the underline only, when the use mouse hovers a string?

Here is [the site](http://dev.alurosu.com/bobo/wis%20site/page.html), in the right corner u will see the menu.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-color + `:hover`

Comment: I tried this .example { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: red;
} but the string color is changing also ...

Comment: @user3503874 Try this solution  http://jsfiddle.net/5CUWs/ with border bottom

Answer (score 2):

**text-decoration-color is only supported by Mozilla.**

What I would suggest is use

**1) border-bottom**

```
a:hover
{
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**OR**

**2) background image in CSS.**

```
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('image.jpg') #FFF repeat-x;
}
```

Make the image suiting your need. And position the background image to bottom. And rest of the color can #FFF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three methods:

1. **Using `text-decoration-color`.**

   ```
   a:hover {text-decoration-color: green; color: blue;}
   ```
2. **Using two DOM elements!**

   ```
   a:hover {color: green; text-decoration: underline;}
   a:hover span {color: blue;}
   ```
3. **Using a `border-bottom`:**

   ```
   a:hover {border-bottom: 1px solid green; color: blue;}
   ```

All the three methods give the same output. Colour with a blue and line with a green!

Also, along with the above methods, there are a lot: [Crafting link underlines](https://medium.com/designing-medium/7c03a9274f9). Thanks to [srekoble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841273/srekoble).

Comment: There more than 3 ways, for example gradient have a look at this great article https://medium.com/designing-medium/7c03a9274f9

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen" />
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
color: #0000FF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0000FF;
}
a:visited {
color: #0000FF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
a:active {
color: #FF0000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
a:hover {
color: #000000;
border-bottom: 2px solid #DD0000;
}
</style>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Hover this link to view the color change</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change  it simply by adding

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    border-bottom: 0px solid blue;
}
```